# Rails: respond_to js do not render with text is a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a code to responde format js

```
        app = CheckAppExist.new(params[:url])
        if(app.exist?) 
            cookies[:package_name] = app.package_name
            cookies[:app_url] = app.app_url
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html {}
            format.json {}
            format.js { render :text => "200" }
          end
        else
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html {}
            format.json {}
            format.js { render :text => "Url or Package Name is wrong ", status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
```

Code above is work, but when i change respond text with

`format.js { render :text => "200" }`
to `format.js { render :text => "some text here" }`

It don't work. I use rails ujs to send and receive request.

When is text is a String number("200"), method `.on("ajax:success",...)` is run, when text render is String  method `.on("ajax:error",...)` is run.

I don't understand about above error, anyone can help me.
Tks.

Comment: Please elaborate on what "It don't work" means. What's the specific error that's being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render inline: 'your text'
```